# i cant train an encoder rnn for seq2seq model

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

when i want to train an EncoderRNN i get this error

Expected hidden size (2, 1, 300), got [1, 1, 300]

## my code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHDHX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVjKi.png)

## when i set hidden = zeros(2,1,300) i get  this error

RuntimeError: For unbatched 2-D input, hx should also be 2-D but got 3-D tensor

## what should i do ?

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.